# Send a mail to specific address in a custom field when a new comment is made on a specific post

Tags: php, functions, comments

I am trying to send a mail using wp_mail function when a new comment is made to a specific post where a custom field is compiled with a mail.

The function works, but when i try to restrict it to unapproved or approved comments (not for spam) it won't work.
I have a function that send every new comment to spam, and after a moderator will approve the comment or move it out from spam folder (so the status will change to approved or not approved) i would like to send a mail to a specific address:

```
// SEND NEW COMMENTS TO SPAM
function set_new_comment_to_spam($commentId) {
    wp_set_comment_status($commentId, 'spam');
}

add_action('comment_post', 'set_new_comment_to_spam', 10, 1);
// SEND MAIL TO CUSTOM FIELD
function send_comment_email_notification( $comment_ID, $comment_approved, $commentdata) {
    $comment = get_comment( $comment_ID );
    $postid = $comment->comment_post_ID;
    $master_email = get_post_meta( $postid, 'email_custom', true);
    if( $comment_approved != 'spam' && isset( $master_email ) && is_email( $master_email ) ) {
        $message = 'New comment';
        add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', create_function( '', 'return "text/html";' ) );
        wp_mail( $master_email, 'New comment', $message );
    }
}
add_action( 'comment_post', 'send_comment_email_notification', 11, 3 );
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it's not working because you're hooking into `comment_post`, which is when the comment is created If you change the status of the comment, the comment already exists, and therefore no email is generated.

There is a comment status change hook: `comment_{$old_status}_to_{$new_status}`.

It fires anytime a comment's status changes from one specified status to another.

So you might try something like this instead:

```php
function send_comment_email_notification($comment) {
    $master_email = get_post_meta( $comment->comment_post_ID, 'email_custom', true);
    if( isset( $master_email ) && is_email( $master_email ) ) {
        $message = 'New comment';
        add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', create_function( '', 'return "text/html";' ) );
        wp_mail( $master_email, 'New comment', $comment->comment_content );
    }
}
add_action('comment_spam_to_approved', 'send_comment_email_notification');
```

Documentation here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/comment_old_status_to_new_status/

Comment: will this send a mail when the comment is changed to approved or not approved only? Shouldn't be an if statement like:    if( $status = 'approved' ||  $status = 'not approved'  where $status is equal to wp_get_comment_status?

Comment: @Benjamin It will only send an email if the comment is changed from spam to approved, because that's the only time the hook is fired. Also, you may consider storing a comment meta that an email was sent, so that when status is changed back to spam and back to approved, not another email is fired off.

Comment: i've tried with your function but it's not working unluckly :( will check it out later to see what could be wrong with it